# Can I publish an app that requiers an account on a webpage?

Tags: android, ios

I have a webservice that requiers accounts. As a complement I have built an app that can be used with the account on the website.

Do I have to provide the possibility to create an account through the app or is it enough to reference to the website?

Comment: This depends on the policy of the platform where you want to distribute your app. I'm not aware of such requirements on Google Play, however, I can't provide any legal advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to be registered to use the application, you must allow:

- users to register in the app
- users to log in in the app
- allow the users to use the application without any account (maybe with less functionnalities).

If not, the app may be rejected.

Comment: all of theese or one of theese?

Comment: The app basically access the camera and uploads the photos to the users account, I can understand the register part, but using the app without an account does not really make sense... Kind of like the twitter-app without a twitter-account.

Comment: Apple App Store only. As a alternative, you can have a user access the camera and can upload: to your service (with account) but also, to its library, share to Facebook, twitter... This is not complicated to implement, this is also not very useful for the user, but enough to have the app like you need.

Answer (score 0):

there's no Google enforced practices of banning app or anything like this. You can release your app however you prefer.

But be warned that apps with a `Login` button, but if you want to `Sign up` you have to go to the web are usually not very successful apps and have very poor ratings on the Google Play.